# Is that possible to decrease the size of title in toolbar KivyMD

Tags: kivy, kivymd

[**Is that possible to decrease the size of title in toolbar KivyMD**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS54Y.png)

Comment: Please post actual code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In your case, you can access the `font_style` attribute through the `ids`:

```
self.root.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title.font_style = 'H1'
```

(Assuming this is executed in a method of the `App` with the `Screen` as the root).